# How to validate that an excel file has been imported into MS Access successfully?

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel, ms-access-2007

Can't seem to find this answer anywhere online, so here we go.

I have a bit of code that pulls in an excel file and inputs its data into a table into a table within MS Access 2007.

How can I validate that the file has imported successfully?

For example:

```
If excel did import Then
MsgBox "Import successful"
Else If Excel didnt import
MsgBox "Import Not successful"
```

I am currently importing the excel file by using the following code:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "tblData", "FilePath", True, "Sheet1!"
```

Thanks

Comment: How exactly are you performing the import in Access?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that, the code is added above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got it after looking around!

Put this code after the 'DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet' code.

```
If DBEngine.Errors.Count = 0 Then

    MsgBox "Imported data successfully!"

ElseIf DBEngine.Errors.Count > 0 Then

    MsgBox "The file did not import!"
    Exit Sub

End If
```

Comment: While this answer solved a problem I found that `DBEngine.Errors.Count` was 1 before the transfer command. No errors were otherwise triggered. So I modified the above procedure to set a variable equal to `DBEngine.Errors.Count` before the transfer and tested whether `DBEngine.Errors.Count` increased after the transfer command.